# Why does tcpdump take so long to read pcap files?

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump, pcap

I am using a third-party tool that captures network traffic as a pcap file during a network test. When I attempt to play these files back, I use the `tcpdump` tool with the `-Aq -r` options, and pipe the output to grep. Some of the captures are 600 KB in size, which doesn't seem huge, but they still take a relatively long time to read.

Is `tcpdump` reading the pcap file back in real time, and – if so – how can I speed it up?

This is what my chosen `tcpdump` options do:

- `-A` prints packets (minus header) in ASCII, so it's grep- and human-friendly.
- `-q` prints less information, for faster output.
- `-r <FILE>` reads in the given pcap file.

This is an example of an actual command that I've run, where it took forty-five seconds to print sixteen lines, when I would have expected the execution time to be near-instant, or a few seconds at most:

```
$ tcpdump -Aq -r z2121ecbc0186d9fa07b.pcap | grep POST
```

Given that the duration of the capture is less than a minute, I'm starting to think that `tcpdump -r` causes the capture to play back in real time, but I can't find anything in the man page or online to confirm that, and certainly nothing that tells me if there is a way to turn that off real-time playback.

Comment: You say that it takes a long time, but you never say how long that time is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `-n` to suppress DNS lookups.

Reading the file, analyzing it and transforming it to text output is usuall very fast and can only take time if the file is *very* large. In all other cases it's the name resolution that slows things down, typicaly waiting for a DNS server to answer and sometimes wating for timeout if it doesn't.

There's no playback in real time and no reason for that. When used with a file, tcpdump just transforms the file into readable output.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank-you so much. I would never have thought of that. Too bad that I can't give you more than one up-vote.

Comment: My pleasure. I'm working with various networking tools on a daily basis and suppressing any potential DNS lookups is a must.